# How to integrate the InAppSettingsKit?

Tags: ios, settings, inappsettingskit

I have just downloaded the InAppSettingsKit and I'm trying to integrate it with my app however I'm having some issues with it since I can't find any documentation to help me out. So far I've done the following steps...

1. I added the InAppSettingsKit directory to my Xcode project.
2. I created a new UIViewController class for my settings (which I named settingViewController).

At this point I have become a bit stuck as I'm not sure what needs to be done. If someone could offer some steps on how to integrate this it would be really really helpful as I can't find any up to date documentation online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, you don't need 2. You just configure a button action to display `IASKAppSettingsViewController`. This could look like this (in this case for a modal presentation):

```
appSettingsViewController = [[[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IASKAppSettingsView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
appSettingsViewController.delegate = self;
appSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appSettingsViewController] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
```

Check `MainViewController.m` in the sample app for different ways to present it (navigation push, tabBarItem, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to do this so that my settings bundle is displayed. However is does't seem to display like shown on the [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) website. It is displaying is a full screen list similar to the contacts list on iPhone. I'm also unsure on how to handle changes to the settings. Is there a delegate method or something?

Comment: Sounds like the tableView style is plain, not grouped. This might happen if IASK wasn't correctly loaded from the NIB. How are you displaying IASK (push, modal or tabBarItem)? To the other question: yes, there's a delegate callback for changes. Check http://inappsettingskit.com for details.

Comment: I don't think I was loading it correctly - I have managed to fix this now. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thanks, @OrtwinGentz! :)